# Position several sets of circles on same SVG with D3.JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

Small circles with different radius grouped in bigger circles

Here is what I have so far - one circle: http://jsfiddle.net/dmitrychuba/hqy6q6qv/

```
(function () {
var rand = function (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};

var width = 400,
    height = 400,
    root = {
        "name": "A",
            "size": 12323,
            "children": [{
            "name": "B",
                "size": 3938
        }, {
            "name": "C",
                "size": 3812
        }, {
            "name": "D",
                "size": 6714
        }, {
            "name": "E",
                "size": 743
        }, {
            "name": "B1",
                "size": 3938
        }, {
            "name": "C1",
                "size": 3812
        }, {
            "name": "D1",
                "size": 6714
        }, {
            "name": "E1",
                "size": 743
        }, {
            "name": "B1",
                "size": 3938
        }, {
            "name": "C1",
                "size": 3812
        }, {
            "name": "D1",
                "size": 6714
        }, {
            "name": "E1",
                "size": 743
        }, {
            "name": "B1",
                "size": 3938
        }, {
            "name": "C1",
                "size": 3812
        }, {
            "name": "D1",
                "size": 6714
        }, {
            "name": "E1",
                "size": 743
        }, {
            "name": "B1",
                "size": 3938
        }, {
            "name": "C1",
                "size": 3812
        }, {
            "name": "D1",
                "size": 6714
        }, {
            "name": "E1",
                "size": 743
        }, {
            "name": "B1",
                "size": 3938
        }, {
            "name": "C1",
                "size": 3812
        }, {
            "name": "D1",
                "size": 6714
        }, {
            "name": "E1",
                "size": 743
        }, {
            "name": "B1",
                "size": 3938
        }, {
            "name": "C1",
                "size": 3812
        }, {
            "name": "D1",
                "size": 6714
        }, {
            "name": "E1",
                "size": 743
        }, {
            "name": "B1",
                "size": 3938
        }, {
            "name": "C1",
                "size": 3812
        }, {
            "name": "D1",
                "size": 6714
        }, {
            "name": "E1",
                "size": 743
        }, {
            "name": "B1",
                "size": 3938
        }, {
            "name": "C1",
                "size": 3812
        }, {
            "name": "D1",
                "size": 6714
        }, {
            "name": "E1",
                "size": 743
        }, {
            "name": "B1",
                "size": 3938
        }, {
            "name": "C1",
                "size": 3812
        }, {
            "name": "D1",
                "size": 6714
        }, {
            "name": "E1",
                "size": 743
        }, {
            "name": "B1",
                "size": 3938
        }, {
            "name": "C1",
                "size": 3812
        },

        ]
    };
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .linkDistance(function (d) {
    return 100;
}) // link distance between the nodes
.charge(-200) // charge that repel nodes from each other
.gravity(0.1)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("#main-container").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");
//Fix the position of the nodes and doesnt allow them to move out of the screen
flatten(root); //to set ids

update();

function update() {
    var nodes = flatten(root),
        links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);
    // Restart the force layout.
    force.nodes(nodes)
        .links(links)
        .start();


    // Update nodes.
    node = node.data(nodes, function (d) {
        return d.id;
    });

    node.exit().remove();

    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node");

    //Adjusting the node sizes according to the children
    nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .style("display", function (d) {
        return d.children ? "none" : "";
    })
        .attr("stroke", 'black')
        .attr("r", function (d) {
        var r = rand(6, 18);
        return d._children ? d.size ? 14 : 18 : d.children ? 24 : r;
    });

    nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function (d) {
        return d.name;
    }).style("display", function (d) {
        return d.children ? "none" : "";
    })
        .style("font-size", function (d) {
        return 10;
    });

    node.select("circle")
        .style("fill", color);
}

function tick() {
    link.attr("x1", function (d) {
        return d.source.x;
    })
        .attr("y1", function (d) {
        return d.source.y;
    })
        .attr("x2", function (d) {
        return d.target.x;
    })
        .attr("y2", function (d) {
        return d.target.y;
    });

    node.attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
}

function color(d) {
    return "#fd8d3c";
}


// Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
    var nodes = [],
        i = 0;

    function recurse(node) {
        if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
        if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
        nodes.push(node);
    }

    recurse(root);
    return nodes;
}

setInterval(function () {
    force.alpha(.1);
}, 100);
})();
```

In order to make several circles I just do 'for' loop here: http://jsfiddle.net/dmitrychuba/hm72c74a/, but this way I have several SVG elements, which is not very good as I can't get them position like on image above(closer to each other). And also I will need few smaller solid circles plus future ability to zoom-in/out.

So my question is: is there a way to have multiple sets of circles on same SVG and with few solid circles and with ability to zoom-in/out?

Thanks
Dmitry

Answer (score 2):

It is better to put all circle groups and individual circles inside a group element rather than putting them as separate SVG. Try as shown below.

```js
var rand = function(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};

var width = 400,
  height = 400,
  root = {
    "name": "A",
    "size": 12323,
    "children": [{
        "name": "B",
        "size": 3938
      }, {
        "name": "C",
        "size": 3812
      }, {
        "name": "D",
        "size": 6714
      }, {
        "name": "E",
        "size": 743
      }, {
        "name": "B1",
        "size": 3938
      }, {
        "name": "C1",
        "size": 3812
      }, {
        "name": "D1",
        "size": 6714
      }, {
        "name": "E1",
        "size": 743
      }, {
        "name": "B1",
        "size": 3938
      }, {
        "name": "C1",
        "size": 3812
      }, {
        "name": "D1",
        "size": 6714
      }, {
        "name": "E1",
        "size": 743
      }, {
        "name": "B1",
        "size": 3938
      }, {
        "name": "C1",
        "size": 3812
      }, {
        "name": "D1",
        "size": 6714
      }, {
        "name": "E1",
        "size": 743
      }, {
        "name": "B1",
        "size": 3938
      }, {
        "name": "C1",
        "size": 3812
      }, {
        "name": "D1",
        "size": 6714
      }, {
        "name": "E1",
        "size": 743
      }, {
        "name": "B1",
        "size": 3938
      }, {
        "name": "C1",
        "size": 3812
      }, {
        "name": "D1",
        "size": 6714
      }, {
        "name": "E1",
        "size": 743
      }, {
        "name": "B1",
        "size": 3938
      }, {
        "name": "C1",
        "size": 3812
      }, {
        "name": "D1",
        "size": 6714
      }, {
        "name": "E1",
        "size": 743
      }, {
        "name": "B1",
        "size": 3938
      }, {
        "name": "C1",
        "size": 3812
      }, {
        "name": "D1",
        "size": 6714
      }, {
        "name": "E1",
        "size": 743
      }, {
        "name": "B1",
        "size": 3938
      }, {
        "name": "C1",
        "size": 3812
      }, {
        "name": "D1",
        "size": 6714
      }, {
        "name": "E1",
        "size": 743
      }, {
        "name": "B1",
        "size": 3938
      }, {
        "name": "C1",
        "size": 3812
      }, {
        "name": "D1",
        "size": 6714
      }, {
        "name": "E1",
        "size": 743
      }, {
        "name": "B1",
        "size": 3938
      }, {
        "name": "C1",
        "size": 3812
      },

    ]
  };

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 10])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);
var color = d3.scale.category10();
var svg = d3.select("#main-container").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width * 3)
  .attr("height", height * 2)
  .call(zoom);
var mainContainer = svg.append("g");

function zoomed() {
  mainContainer.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
var positions = [
  [0, 0],
  [width, 0],
  [width * 2, 0],
  [width - 200, height],
  [width * 2 - 200, height]
];

function addCircle(x, y) {
  mainContainer.append("circle")
    .style("fill", "#3D91B2")
    .attr("cx", x)
    .attr("cy", y)
    .attr("r", 50);
}
addCircle(width, height - 70);
addCircle(width * 2, height - 70);


for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  (function() {
    var force = d3.layout.force()
      .linkDistance(function(d) {
        return 100;
      }) // link distance between the nodes
      .charge(-200) // charge that repel nodes from each other
      .gravity(0.1)
      .size([width, height])
      .on("tick", tick);

    var gContainer = mainContainer.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + positions[i][0] + "," + positions[i][1] + ")");

    var link = gContainer.selectAll(".link"),
      node = gContainer.selectAll(".node");
    //Fix the position of the nodes and doesnt allow them to move out of the screen
    flatten(root); //to set ids

    update(i);

    function update(colorIdx) {
      var nodes = flatten(root),
        links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);
      // Restart the force layout.
      force.nodes(nodes)
        .links(links)
        .start();


      // Update nodes.
      node = node.data(nodes, function(d) {
        return d.id;
      });

      node.exit().remove();

      var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node");

      //Adjusting the node sizes according to the children
      nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .style("display", function(d) {
          return d.children ? "none" : "";
        })
        .attr("stroke", 'black')
        .attr("r", function(d) {
          var r = rand(6, 18);
          return d._children ? d.size ? 14 : 18 : d.children ? 24 : r;
        });

      nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.name;
        }).style("display", function(d) {
          return d.children ? "none" : "";
        })
        .style("font-size", function(d) {
          return 10;
        });
      node.select("circle")
        .style("fill", color(colorIdx));
    }

    function tick() {
      link.attr("x1", function(d) {
          return d.source.x;
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
          return d.source.y;
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
          return d.target.x;
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
          return d.target.y;
        });

      node.attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      });
    }


    // Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
    function flatten(root) {
      var nodes = [],
        i = 0;

      function recurse(node) {
        if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
        if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
        nodes.push(node);
      }

      recurse(root);
      return nodes;
    }

  })();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot for your answer. Is there a way to apply force layout to bigger circles space also so they position closer and be more random like on picture ? Thank!

Comment: Why don't you calculate some random positions by yourselves for the bigger circles? I think it won't be difficult..

Comment: Hi @Gilsha, I would do probably able to do it, but I'm afraid circles may overlap each other. And I can't figure out how to apply force layout to bigger circles so they can act like smaller ones while 'other force layout' applied for smaller circles.. So this is tricky for me